# Two way data Binding issue with combo box - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a View that contains a `Combobox`. The `Combobox` `SelectedItem` property is data bound to `SelectedX` property of View Model as two way data binding. When the viewModel is initialized, the `SelectedX` property is set correctly. But after that when the view renders, it resets the value of `SelectedX`(since the binding is two-way).
So the two way data binding for the `Combobox` is basically not working. Please advise.

This is the xaml for my view. I initialize the View model first with apprpriate values for Relationships and SelectedX. When the view renders, the combo box resets the value for SelectedX. (I figured that by adding breakpoints). Hope this helps

```
   <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Background="White"     BorderBrush="DarkGray"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedX, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Relationships}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
              SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding Key, Mode=TwoWay}"
              IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: can you list some key code?

Comment: I think the `ComboBox` `SelctedIndex` has been set? Please post the code you have tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Key, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

This will change the `SelectedItem` to its `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Thanks Sankarann, not adding SelectedValue property solves my rpoblem. You are correct in mentioning that adding this resets the SelectedItem.